# "Splitting" long words

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, typography

I'm making a responsive website for a client using twitter bootstrap, which is responsive by default. However when the words get too long in a `<h1>` it doesn't fit the mobile sized browser.

What I would like to do is change "thisisaverylongword" into "thisisa-verylongword" with the final part on a new line.

Is there a simple way to do this, maybe with javascript? I'm thinking some condition like "if $word is wider than $body then" or something similar. Any tips will be very useful, gold star if the same code works for any word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the (experimental) CSS property [`hyphens`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/hyphens):

```
h1 {
  -webkit-hyphens: manual;
     -moz-hyphens: manual;
      -ms-hyphens: manual;
          hyphens: manual;
}
```

and specify the line break by using special unicode characters:

> **U+2010 (HYPHEN)**
>
> The "hard" hyphen character indicates a visible line break opportunity. Even if the line is not actually broken at that point, the hyphen is still rendered.
>
> **U+00AD (SHY)**
>
> An invisible, "soft" hyphen. This character is not rendered visibly; instead, it suggests a place where the browser might choose to break the word if necessary. In HTML, you can use ­ to insert a soft hyphen.

- [Browser compatibilty](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-hyphens)
- [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/hyphens)

**EDIT**

As mentioned by @hustlerinc it might be needed to set [`word-break: break-all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) to make it work.

Comment: Have a look at word-break 
http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/word-break/ too

Comment: Had some trouble getting it to work until I added word-break: break-all; from the css-tricks link. You might want to add that to your answer if someone runs into the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a jQuery plugin that might fit this purpose quite well. Check out [ellipsis.js](http://bebraw.github.io/ellipsis.js/). Using the following configuration should work:

```
$('h1').ellipsis({visible: 10, more: '…', separator: '', atFront: false})
```

I guess the advantage of doing it this way is that the users still may display the whole header on tap if they want to.

You can apparently achieve something like this with a bit of CSS, check out the [text-overflow](http://quirksmode.org/css/user-interface/textoverflow.html) property. Perhaps that's the ticket for this case. No JS needed. :)

Comment: This could work as a last resort, however the specific word is there for marketing purposes (the reason why I can't just reformulate the header) and should be seen without hassle. Would appreciate it if there was a way not to hide it. The audience aren't computer savvy.

Comment: Valid point. I guess you might need something more dynamic. I really hope there's some nice CSS based solution for this problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

Can't you set the CSS property `word-break` to `hyphenate`?

example [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you must do it by yourself.

With the function "split", you split your string into a table of words. Then, you can check all the words into a for.